# Change date format on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS also affecting Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, date

How can I globally change the date format on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS which also affects Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the `Control Panel`.
2. Click on <kbd>Language Support</kbd> or just call `gnome-language-selector` instead.
3. Switch to the tab <kbd>Regional Format</kbd>.
4. Select your preferred format.
5. Optionally, click the button <kbd>Apply System-Wide</kbd>.

The changes will take effect the next time you log in.